# Show more/Show less form with div's inside in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

So I have a page that describes the amenities in the hotel, how I can create a hidden block of amenities that can be expanded by pressing the **"Show more amenities"** button and collapsed by pressing **"Show less amenities"** in **NextJS** with **tailwind-css**?

**Example 1:**
[image: exmpl-1]

**Example-2:**
[image: exmpl-2]

**Here's a part of the code:**

```
'use client'

import Image from 'next/image'

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Lodge() {

    return (
        <div className="w-full h-[8964px] bg-white shadow-sm">

            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">

                ...

                        <div className="text-[28px] font-medium leading-normal text-[#313131] underline flex flex-row gap-5 py-16 cursor-pointer">
                            Show more amenties
                            <Image
                                src="/images/icon down.svg"
                                alt="icon-down"
                                width={26}
                                height={26}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">

                            <div className="">
                                <div className="text-[32px] font-bold leading-normal text-[#313131]">
                                    Heating & Cooling
                                    <div className="text-[24px] font-medium leading-normal text-[#313131] flex flex-row items-end gap-5">
                                        <Image
                                            src="/images/lodge/fan icon.svg"
                                            alt="fan-icon"
                                            width={40}
                                            height={40}
                                        />
                                        Portable fans
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="text-[32px] font-bold leading-normal text-[#313131]">
                                    Internet & Working
                                    <div className="text-[24px] font-medium leading-normal text-[#313131] flex flex-row items-end gap-5">
                                        <Image
                                            src="/images/lodge/wifi icon.svg"
                                            alt="wifi-icon"
                                            width={40}
                                            height={40}
                                        />
                                        WI-FI
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="text-[24px] font-medium leading-normal text-[#313131] flex flex-row items-end gap-5">
                                        <Image
                                            src="/images/lodge/desk icon.svg"
                                            alt="desk-icon"
                                            width={40}
                                            height={40}
                                        />
                                        Working zone
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             
... etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following example in order to show and hide the element in react js. In here all you need is the usestate hook to do it at once.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setName(!name);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={toggle}>Click me to show/hide the element</h1>

      {name ? <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add/remove the [Tailwind CSS hidden class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#hidden) on click to hide/show the specific content. This changes the display to none.

If you want to change the visibility to hidden instead, use the [invisible class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/visibility#making-elements-invisible).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way:

**Added a separate conditions to each "Show more/show less" condition:**

```
export default function Lodge() {

    const [showAmenities, setShowAmenities] = useState(false); /*amenties*/
    const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false); /*text*/
    const [showRText, setRShowText] = useState(false); /*reviews*/
    const [showLText, setLShowText] = useState(false); /*location*/
    const [showLsText, setLsShowText] = useState(false); /*location second*/

    return (
       ...
  )
}
```

**Then wrapped my hidden elements this way:**

```
<div className={`${showAmenities ? '' : 'hidden'}
   ...
</div>
```

**And added the buttons below:**

```
{/* Show more button */}
<button onClick={() => setShowAmenities(true)} 
    className={`text-[28px] font-medium leading-normal text-[#313131] underline flex flex-row gap-5 pt-10 
    ${showAmenities ? 'hidden' : ''}`}>
    Show more amenities
    <Image src="/images/icon down.svg" alt="icon-down" width={26} height={26}/>
</button>

{/* Show less button */}
<button onClick={() => setShowAmenities(false)} 
    className={`text-[28px] font-medium leading-normal text-[#313131] underline flex flex-row gap-5 pt-10
    ${showAmenities ? '' : 'hidden'}`}>
    Show less amenities
    <Image src="/images/icon up.svg" alt="icon-up" width={26} height={26} />
</button>
```